# Kivy animate all objects of one specific class

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

Is there any way in kivy to animate all objects of some class? I have kv code like:

```
<SomeLabel@Label>:
    size_hint_x = .5

MainBoxLayout:

    some_labels: [some_label1, some_label2, some_label3]

    BoxLayout:
        SomeLabel:
            id: some_label1
        SomeLabel:
            id: some_label2
        SomeLabel:
            id: some_label3
```

and Python code:

```
class MainBoxLayout(BoxLayout):

    def animate_margins(self):
        for some_label in self.some_labels:
            Animation(size_hint_x=.1, d=.3, t='out_quint').start(some_label)
```

It doesn't look so bad but in real program i have 10 labels like this and it may be more in future, so i wonder if there's any way not to assign this ids and just animate all items of some class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a static list on the custom widget you make, which contains all instances of it.
One way of doing that is to append them in the `__init__` method.
In this exampe I make an animate `ToggleButton` for you to test:

```py
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


class SomeLabel(Label):
    instances = []
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SomeLabel,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        SomeLabel.instances.append(self.proxy_ref)


class MainBoxLayout(BoxLayout):

    def animate_margins(self,state):
        x, d = (.1, .3) if state == 'down' else (1, 1)
        for some_label in SomeLabel.instances:
            Animation(size_hint_x=x, d=d, t='out_quint').start(some_label)


root = Builder.load_string('''

MainBoxLayout:

    BoxLayout:
        ToggleButton:
            text: 'Animate'
            on_release: root.animate_margins(self.state)
        SomeLabel:
            text: 'Label 1'
        SomeLabel:
            text: 'Label 2'
        SomeLabel:
            text: 'Label 3'


''')   


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return root


MyApp().run()
```